# Gradient boosting algorithm implemented in LightGBM

Tags: binary-classification, lightgbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I'm currently reading the documentation of LightGBM and I'm wondering which gradient boosting algorithm is exactly implemented there if choose boosting parameter as "gbdt" or "dart?" Is it just a  simple algorithm as presented below?
[image]
I'm especially interested in binary classification with a Log Loss as the objective function and how L1 and L2 regularization is implemented in this specific case.
Thanks in advance.